# Getting error when returning list from rest service admin-on-rest

Tags: admin-on-rest

I'm getting the following error on my first admin component.

`uncaught at handleFetch TypeError: newRecords.reduce is not a function`

When I attempt to query my rest-api. I'm using the majority of the supplied simple rest client with some additional security headers thrown in.

My response from my API is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Range: Account 0-0/1
Server: Kestrel
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Range
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:9f32da6c-a0dd-445f-b59f-d5d01ee6c462
X-AA-Request-ID: ad76be2b-0a29-4179-8fab-6ac0b83e411b
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RTpcRGV2XEFBSHViXEFBLkh1Yi5TZXR0aW5ncy5TZXJ2aWNlXEFBLkh1Yi5TZXR0aW5ncy5TZXJ2aWNlXGFwaVx2MVxhY2NvdW50?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 15 Aug 2017 02:56:56 GMT
```

The body of the response has:

```
{"data":[{"changeManagements":[],"serviceProfiles":[],"id":1,"login":"cuken","permissionLevel":9001,"note":"This is a dev test user"}],"totalItems":1}
```

EDIT

Here is the fetch.js file I modified from the simple rest client example:

```
import HttpError from './HttpError';

export const fetchJson = (url, options = {}) => {
    const requestHeaders = options.headers || new Headers({
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'X-AA-ClientName': 'fc5f3712-64fc-4ca4-9e5f-d4b6edeb46d4',
        'X-AA-ApiKey': '80b4ccbf-a741-42ad-aacc-50c4309de8e6',
    });
    if (!(options && options.body && options.body instanceof FormData)) {
        requestHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }
    if (options.user && options.user.authenticated && options.user.token) {
        requestHeaders.set('Authorization', options.user.token);
    }

    return fetch(url, { ...options, headers: requestHeaders })
        .then(response => response.text().then(text => ({
            status: response.status,
            statusText: response.statusText,
            headers: response.headers,
            body: text,
        })))
        .then(({ status, statusText, headers, body }) => {
            let json;
            try {
                json = JSON.parse(body);
            } catch (e) {
                // not json, no big deal
            }
            if (status < 200 || status >= 300) {
                return Promise.reject(new HttpError((json && json.message) || statusText, status));
            }
            return { status, headers, body, json };
        });
};

export const queryParameters = data => Object.keys(data)
    .map(key => [key, data[key]].map(encodeURIComponent).join('='))
    .join('&');
```

The simple.js file is an exact copy from the repo.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do you have an auth client?

Comment: No auth client, I just added some headers to the simple rest api provided;
I've updated the question above to show the rest api and the corresponding fetch.js file I'm using

Comment: Do you ming sharing your restClient please ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a dedicated auth client to handle the auth types and shoot the appropriate actions

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Admin.html#authclient

Comment: The auth headers for my requests need to be on every get/post:

'X-AA-ClientName': 'fc5f3712-64fc-4ca4-9e5f-d4b6edeb46d4',
'X-AA-ApiKey': '80b4ccbf-a741-42ad-aacc-50c4309de8e6',

But my api is checking them from the request itself, not from a separate call. I'm still required to have the auth client for something like this?

Comment: The auth client checks every call response to check whether the user has a valid session or not. The docs are quite explanatory. And its pretty simple code. Feel free to ask questions if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure why this isn't clicking with me but according to the documentation:
`The <Admin> component creates an application with its own state, routing, and controller logic. <Admin> requires only a restClient and at least one child <Resource> to work:`

My question isn't around the proper way to handle authentication, my question is around without using the auth client, why am I getting the above error on what looks like to me a valid rest response to the simple client.

Comment: Can you share your admin component please.

Comment: Go into node_modules/admin-on-rest/lib/reducer/resource/data.js and try and take console.logs and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your API response is not what the `simpleRestClient` expects:

It should only contains

```
[{"changeManagements":[],"serviceProfiles":[],"id":1,"login":"cuken","permissionLevel":9001,"note":"This is a dev test user"}]
```

No `data` nor `totalItems` keys. As stated in the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#simple-rest):

> The simple REST client expects the API to include a Content-Range header in the response to GET_LIST calls. The value must be the total number of resources in the collection. This allows admin-on-rest to know how many pages of resources there are in total, and build the pagination controls.